# How to (actually) load RichTextBox from VB.NET in VS2022

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox, visual-studio-2022

Have spent hours on hours exploring "solutions" that surely worked for someone, sometime, somewhere.
Alas NONE seem to work when I try to do so creating a Windows Desktop App using VB.NET in VS2022.  Has something changed?  Am I just plain dense.

Tried the obvious...  RichTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText("C:\Temp\Results.txt"), followed by several alternatives, e.g. moving the file to the \bin file of the code etc. ALL futile.

Will TRY to add screen shots of significant issues, e.g. does the file exist...  I say try because haven't yet learned how to deal with the "add [Text File where stated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdrQ4.png)a picture: feature, beyond adding only one.

[Text file content in Notepad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7hIa.png)

[Simple Code that fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uozNj.png)

Comment: Are you sure the real extension of that file (so, it's full name), is actually `.txt`? Are you hiding known extensions in your Explorer view? Other files there have no extension...

Comment: Put Explorer into programmer mode.  View > tick "File name extensions".

Comment: Three files without extension and one with extension. Surely this hints to what @HansPassant says

Comment: Just to be clear, what everyone is pointing towards here in case you've not figured.  Your file name is actually C:\Temp\Results.txt.txt.  You've doubled the extension.  That aside, for future reference, maybe read over [Ask].  Particularly about posting images of code

Comment: Thanks to all for providing simple clear answers that thankfully didn't "assume" that I already knew what might be so obvious to others.  Very much appreciated!

Comment: Great thoughts re how to do things better - OK I haven't tried them yet but will.  Explorer "programmer mode" - that should be revealing.  As for inadvertently redundant file extensions:  tried hard to make sure that was NOT the case, but alas, maybe... That Windows has become "new and improved" so that file extensions are hidden so well, ....  Yes I need to adapt I suppose or find other alternatives.

Comment: Yes, the "file extension" aspect has become a thorn in my side.  Know exactly what they are and why used, but alas have some difficulty creating them it seems and/or seeing what they are.  Appreciate your time and effort in pointing this out, seriously.  And yes will attack the problem with more persistence in my future work, now mostly for developing useful applications (well for me, probably others) such as the ability to quickly, easily determine if/when it would pay-off to swap a current CD for another - the stuff that is important to retire people not used to be retired! Thank you...

Answer (score -1):

This is C# code if you Google C# to VB.Net you will find a code converter
Now that you have the naming issue solved and the Path correct This code will load txt data to a listBox just change the name for your RichTextBox
You might like to consider SQLite if you want to store data much better!

```
private void btnMakeDB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox.Items.Clear();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            string line;
            // Read and display lines from the file until the end of
            // the file is reached.
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {

                listBox.Items.Add(line);
                textBox.Text = line;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Will definitely look into SQLite.  Been a BIG fan of SQL since developing useful apps in Oracle v4.1??? in the 1970s.